# Div's don't show when I give a percentage value width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes in a `div`. I'm trying to create a each box being a third of it's container width size, so all 3 boxes should fill it's container `div`. I'm also trying to have a max size for them.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpg8bvtp/1/).

The problem is, the 3 box's don't show at all. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have given width: 33..3%;  Remove one dot.

Comment: The height changed, but that's it. The width is the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width of the `#boxContainer` to fill all the space. You put 2 dots in the width of the the `.box`. And you didn't put a real "height" to the `.box`, `height: 100%` don't work well for non-absolute or fixed elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/wpg8bvtp/4/

**PS 1:** Don't forget you have a `max-width` in the `.box`, that's why the box is not filling all the width.

**PS 2:** You border is out from the first container, so you can use `box-sizing: border-box` to fix it. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/wpg8bvtp/11/).

**PS 3:** If you wanna make it responsive, you can simply add a `media query` making `.box` to use 100% of the width and set `max-width` to 160px. [You can see it in this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/wpg8bvtp/15/)

Comment: Thank you! When you size the window very small, the boxes become skinnier and the third one goes to the next line. How can I make the boxes size smaller, with keeping it's aspect ratio?

Comment: You can make a media query, i'm gonna add this in the answer.

Comment: I hope this isn't getting too confusing... I want all boxes to stay in the first line. when the outer box becomes too small, the boxes should resize itself with the aspect ratio. If you want an example of what I mean, then you can check out https://speeddial2.com/.

Comment: When you are using `inline-block`, a margin is added between the elements, so that's why the element is going to the bottom, even using `33.3%`. Here is a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/wpg8bvtp/16/

Comment: What about keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: Same width and height, that is what you mean?

Comment: That's more complex. A way is use javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/wpg8bvtp/17/